# Java passing int value/data

Tags: java, integer

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code? I get `0` from return of the calculation.

Created a small calculation on second class and pass the result data to main class, then print.

**main class**

```
package javaapplication3;

public class JavaApplication3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        cal bla = new cal();

        bla.getRatio();
        String dCount = String.valueOf(bla.getRatio());

        System.out.print(dCount);

    }
}
```

**second class**

```
package javaapplication3;

public class cal {

    public int total = 11;
    public int count = 2508;
    public int calRatio;

    public void caln () {

        calRatio = count / total;

        System.out.print(calRatio);

    }

    public int getRatio () {
        return (calRatio);
    }

}
```

PS: By changing bla.getRatio to bla.caln(); worked. I think I've got other projects mixed up. Thanks for the input guys.

Comment: In addition to the answer, you'll want to look at [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), specifically how to name classes/public methods/etc.

Comment: Removed the `[pass-by-reference]` as a) Java doesn't support pass by reference, b) it doesn't relate to the question.

Comment: As a general rule, you should *never* begin your question with "what's wrong with the code?"

Comment: Sorry guys, I will be more specific next time and accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call the "setter" function caln(), so `calRatio` was never set. So it returns the 0 for `calRatio`.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing integer division, which truncates the result to an integer.

You need to cast either operand to `double`.

Comment: Actually he is never calling "caln" which I think it was intended as a constructor (maybe?) so no calculation takes place. "calRatio" is initialized as 0 and it remains like that.

Comment: changed int to double and still get 0.0?

Answer (score 3):

```
bla.getRatio();
String dCount = String.valueOf(bla.getRatio());
```

You never call the caln()-method, so calRatio is 0 forever.

Maybe you meant the following:

```
bla.caln();
String dCount = String.valueOf(bla.getRatio());
```

Plus, you try to divide integers. Try this:

```
public class cal {

    public int total = 11;
    public int count = 2508;
    public double calRatio;

    public void caln () {

        calRatio = count / total;

        System.out.print(calRatio);

    }

    public double getRatio () {
        return calRatio;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not just that, but his method does integer division.

Comment: @TimoteeTheCodeMonkee correct, but in this specific case result of count /total equals 228

Comment: And in the event where his values are no longer hard coded? Better to teach good programming practices than hacked solutions. :)

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
public void caln () {

    calRatio = count / total;

    System.out.print(calRatio);

}
```

by this

```
public cal () {

    calRatio = count / total;

    System.out.print(calRatio);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get 0 from return of the calculation.

As you should. `11 / 2508` does an integer division which is `0`

If you want a non-zero I suggest changing

```
    public double getAverage () {
        return (double) total / count;
    }
```

Normally you divide the total by the count to get the average.

Comment: The OP also never calls the setter function `caln()` so he needs to change that in addition to doing double division.

Comment: @NominSim I am assuming the `caln()` and the field set doesn't really need to be there.  This method will work without calling another method first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        cal bla = new cal();
        bla.caln();
        String dCount = String.valueOf(bla.getRatio());

        System.out.print(dCount);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It will return 0, always, because you are returning an `int` type. The result of your division will always be some floating point value, so you need to store it as such, and return it.

```
public class cal {
    public int total = 11;
    public int count = 2508;
    public double calRatio;
    public void caln() {
        calRatio = (double)count / (double)total;
        System.out.print(calRatio);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, downvoted because division is 2508/11=228, not the contrary

Comment: I suspect the OP has the count and total the wrong way around. ;)

Comment: Fixed. Small typo, the concept is the same, nonetheless.

Comment: Still this doesn't solve his issue, since he is actually not calling the setter function.